# String formatting -- skip one format string

Tags: python, sql

I have the following sql statement:

```
SELECT_CLAUSE += ", IF(%s IS NULL, -1, %s=%s) AS %s_score" % (
    field, field, '%s', field
)
```

Basically I want to string-format everything except for the second-to-last format string so it looks like:

```
field = 'name'
SELECT_CLAUSE += ', IF(name IS NULL, -1, name=%s) AS name_score'
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to repeat formatting values? you can do for example named formatting parameters:  `', IF({field} IS NULL, -1, {field}={value}) AS name_score'.format(field='name', value='1')`

Comment: Well, I think that's a bit more advanced where I'm looking for. I'm basically just trying to keep the '%s' in there so I can format it at a later line of code.

Comment: You could store this string for example: `s = ', IF({0} IS NULL, -1, {0}={1}) AS name_score'` and then later do `s.format('name', 'value')` for formatting it.

Comment: I want to point out that mostly concatenating SQL string manually is not recommended. As there might be injections, mostly there will be some functions like `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID == ?", (Id,))` to safely concatenate your SQL string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double `%%` the single `%` to escape it:

```
SELECT_CLAUSE += ", IF(%s IS NULL, -1, %s=%%s) AS %s_score" % (
    field, field, field
)
```

Where is the StringBorg that we direly need? That would make this safe.

Comment: Thanks I ended up using this approach, it was the most similar to what I already had!

Comment: (Note you don't need the extra '%s' in the args when you've already done it in the string like you mentioned.) -- `>>> ", IF(%s IS NULL, -1, %s=%%s) AS %s_score" % ('name', 'name', 'name')`
`', IF(name IS NULL, -1, name=%s) AS name_score'`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.format()` to do that, for example:

```
field = 'name'
SELECT_CLAUSE += ', IF({name} IS NULL, -1, {name}=%s) AS {name}_score'.format(name=field)
```

In addition, if you're using python 3.6+  you could use format string by specifying variable name in braces:

```
field = 'name'
SELECT_CLAUSE += f', IF({field} IS NULL, -1, {field}=%s) AS {field}_score'
```